# What does ruby httpclient timeout mean?

Tags: timeout, httpclient

I am interested in ruby httpclient timeout such as send_timeout and receive_timeout. So what does these values actually mean? For instance, default send_timeout is 60s, then does it mean http connection will last for 60s? Exactly speaking, if the file to be upload is 61MB and network speed is 1MB/s, then can I upload the file? Will it cause send timeout exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance, default send_timeout is 60s, then does it mean http connection will last for 60s.

Exactly speaking, if the file to be upload is 61MB and network speed is 1MB/s, then it will cause send timeout exception?